# discrete triangle generator

Tags: comparator, waveform

I am trying to design a convertor from analog to PWM with very good THD as in this http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau508/slau508.pdf

The triangle generator  (fig 2) (I am trying for 750Khz to 1Mhz) is a very important aspect and any malformations or jitter will directly impact the THD

I have a second circuit that can make triangle waveform (you can see it http://www.circuitstoday.com/triangular-wave-generator from cmos input)

Anyone has any experience with those , what design should I concentrate on ?

Comment: Use integrators, just like in their app note. Try and error, nothing else.

Comment: what output filter must you use, to achieve very good THD?

Comment: Even ignoring the GBW, the 741 has a guaranteed slew rate of only 0.3V/us, and it's only guaranteed to be that "good" at room temperature. So if your 1MHz triangle is more than 150mVp-p (0.075V peak) the 741 won't even try to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to design a converter from analog to PWM with very good THD

The design you link uses a comparator with quite poor input offset voltage. Typically it is +/- 1 mV but can be as high as +/- 6.5 mV. Given that the triangle wave is 4 volts peak to peak, that's a worst case measurement error of 6.5 mV in 2 volts or 0.325%. Bear also in mind that the offset voltage can drift by 5 uV/degC so this error can move around a bit.

Given also that your proposed triangle wave generator (your 2nd link) is based on an article that uses a 741 op-amp you are going to be greatly disappointed because it will never hack 1 MHz with any measure of waveform linearity quality or amplitude stability.

Even the choice of resistors can make a good THD figure turn out bad due to temperature stability and the p-p triangle waveform changing with time and heat.

If you are trying to get better than 1% THD at the speed you want, it is not a trivial design and needs considerable care in component choice.

> Anyone has any experience with those , what design should I
>   concentrate on ?

Try looking at the Linear Tech LTC6992 as a reasonable example of an integrated PWM chip. Read the data sheet and try to imagine what your circuit needs to do to achieve its performance: -

[image]

Comment: Agreed but as you can see they got 0.009. Can you suggest a better comparator ?We could potentially use a lower frequency at 500-750Khz

Comment: My suggestion is to use much higher voltage supply rails with a much larger peak-to-peak triangle wave then, the input offset becomes relatively much smaller. You will find it hard to find a better comparator at that sort of speed that doesn't cause other problems like delay. An alternative is to demod the signal back to a proper analogue signal and use negative feedback to ensure stability.

Answer (score 1):

First, any µA741 based design will not work at 1MHz. You need an op-amp with higher gain-bandwidth product.

The TI design uses a Schmitt trigger to monitor the actual voltage level of the integrator. That's the key feature of that design.

The other design in contrary relies on the pulse-pause ratio of the input square wave. This simpler idea ignores any inital voltage present on the integration capacitor, which would create a random offset you cannot trim away manually. That's why there must be a discharge resistor parallel to the capacitor in that design. That discharge resistor distorts the triangle, unfortunately.

Comment: OK got you , we are also thinking the TI design was better. What should we look in a comparator specs to improve the triangle generator ?

Comment: That comparator needs a push-pull output. Most have open drain. Speed isn't a problem as a slow loop results in a constant added to the peak.